# ZF routing based on action name when controller name is not provided?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to route non-existent controllers to (when applicable) actions of the index controller. Is this possible?

Example:

```
IndexController
  fooAction
```

When I acces http://host/foo/, I want to be directed to http://host/index/foo

Is this possible?

Comment: (1) http://blog.jebrini.net/post/1431025228/url-routing-in-zend-framework-for-dummies  (2) http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: I know about routing. Was more the question if this was biult-in or not. Guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such built in routing possible in Zend Framework. Either you can add a router to route

```
foo
```

to

```
Controller - Index, Action - foo
```

using the following code.

```
routes.foo.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.foo.route = "foo"
routes.foo.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.foo.defaults.action = "foo"
```

Or you can modify the default way of router behavior, which will be challenge for a beginner.